# How does Buctools work?

Tags: web-filtering, internet-filter

I have set up [buctools](http://www.buctools.com/how-it-works/buc-web-filter.html) in my house, but I am curious: how does it technologically work and do all those things? -- like safesearch for example.

Hopefully this counts as a "personal and home computer networking" question, and is not an invalid question to ask here ;)

Answer (score 0):

Lots of routers offer web content filtering capabilities. Since the company is selling a router, I would assume theirs works similarly to others' products. If your network traffic is going through their device to reach the Internet, the device can look inside the Internet packets for the domain names your browser is using in its queries to websites. If the device sees www.baddomain.com, checks its list of forbidden sites, and finds that domain is on the list, the connection attempt by your browser goes no further than the router. The device may even look at the URLs for websites or the content of webpages being sent from websites in response to a home system's attempt to view the webpages. E.g., perhaps general traffic to a site, such as www.gooddomain.com is allowed, but access to a particular URL such as www.gooddomain.com/badstuff.html will be blocked. Or, it may look for certain words on the webpage. If "naughty bits" is on its list of content to be blocked and it sees that on the content of a web page, the information won't get passed from the router to the home system that attempted to view the page.

I would expect that they would periodically update lists in the router they provided to block sites and content. Or the router could even direct traffic through some web filtering device at another location, which would analyze traffic from/to your home systems and decide whether it was allowed or should be blocked.

As with all such devices, don't expect perfection. They may be using lists created by other companies and organizations of sites known to host malware, pornography, hate speech, etc. Whether they do that or filter based on lists they created themselves, there is always the chance of some false positives, i.e., sometimes innocent sites/content may get blocked and sometimes there may be false negatives, i.e., a site or content is deemed safe, when it contains content you may find objectionable or which might be dangerous to your system, i.e., malware. That could happen because the site hosting the malware, pornography, etc. has just recently been set up and so hasn't been classified as objectionable yet.